# ALT + TAB pass trough Citrix Workspace not working after Ubuntu upgrade from 22.04 to 22.04.1

Tags: 22.04, citrix

As stated in the title .. after upgrading Ubuntu from 22.04 to 22.04.1 the key combination ALT + TAB is not passed through Citrix Workspace into the Windows Client.
(Citrix is in full screen)

How to fix this ?

Comment: Have you looked at Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts and checked that Alt-Tab is active / default as this mysteriously disabled for me on one of my systems.

Comment: Ubuntu ist the host - disable ALT-Tab on host is my work-around to pass ALT-Tab to Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, and it seems that it has to do with Wayland. In https://askubuntu.com/a/1441971/1685205 user [enthusiast](https://askubuntu.com/users/1651804/enthusiast) states that Citrix is not supported on Wayland.

So a workaround is to switch to X11: At the Ubuntu login screen, after selecting your name, click the gear icon in the bottom right corner of the screen and choose the *Ubuntu on Xorg* option.

I was additionally encountering the [keyboard mapping issue](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/417261-keyboardmapping-failure-on-for-icaclient-227020-0-fedora-using-wayland-display-server-german-keyboard) described in the Citrix support forums. That post gave me a hint that Wayland might also be the reason for this change in the ALT+TAB behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem after updating from 20.x to 22.04 LTS

My "Windows" key is not passed so to add more desktops in the Citrix environment (Windows+D). I now have to do it via the taskbar. It's no biggy, but to fast shift from L->R or vice versa using Windows+left (or right) arrow is cumbersome and slower.

I have no knowledge but can use editors to edit the wfclient.ini but I really don't understand the syntax for these shortcuts. It just makes no sense to me.

Hotkey1Char=F1
  Hotkey1Shift=Shift
  Hotkey2Char=F3
  Hotkey2Shift=Shift
  Hotkey3Char=F2
  Hotkey3Shift=Shift
  Hotkey4Char=F1
  Hotkey4Shift=Ctrl
  Hotkey5Char=F2
  Hotkey5Shift=Ctrl
  Hotkey6Char=F2
  Hotkey6Shift=Alt
  Hotkey7Char=plus
  Hotkey7Shift=Alt
  Hotkey8Char=minus
  Hotkey8Shift=Alt
  Hotkey9Char=F3
  HotKey9Shift=Ctrl
  Hotkey10Char=F5
  HotKey10Shift=Ctrl
  Hotkey11Char=plus
  Hotkey11Shift=Ctrl
  Hotkey12Char=plus
  Hotkey12Shift=Ctrl
  Hotkey13Char=plus
  Hotkey13Shift=Ctrl