# Ubuntu 22.10 and Citrix Workspace App: fullscreen issues

Tags: gnome, fullscreen, citrix

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.10 and I am trying the Citrix Workspace app.
I have 2 screens with different resolutions.

Citrix has always worked well in fullscreen mode with the exact same behaviour as my normal GNOME desktops (re different screen sizes).

Now, it starts well, but as soon as I interact with it, one of the 2 screen becomes a mirror of the other one instead of showing the other half of the remote desktop.

This can repeat when I press the Windows key and go back to it: it is properly repainted and soon after half is lost.

I tried with various versions of Citrix and this always happens.

I think GNOME has changed something, I dont know if the different screen sizes are a red herring or the reason of this issue.

EDIT: Pressing ALT-TAB forces the correct fullscreen window to be re-drawn, one can then see where things are and move them with the mouse. This means to me that the remote connection is happening exactly as it should, but something on the local desktop is causing bad rendering.

Comment: Upgraded from what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: It could be related to Wayland, the default on Ubuntu 22.10 (even after an upgrade)

Comment: I come from 22.04 where this worked with Wayland AND Xorg. Now on 22.10 I have tried Xorg and it works. Not ideal, only a temporary workaround.

Comment: Bad news: I just tried Fedora 37 Beta and the behaviour is exactly the same. I fear we will be stuck with 22.04 or Xorg.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately , it clearly shows on [System requirements and compatibility](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-workspace-app-for-linux/system-requirements.html) that Citrix is not supported on Wayland.

Comment: I think it is a lot more subtle than this. That is probably a corporate disclaimer to justify poor behaviour. I hope it is the same as this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1990563 which seems to have been fixed in mutter 43.1 (untested as of yet).